# Is there documentation on Buildfire integration settings for my plugin to read api keys?

Tags: buildfire

I am building a map plugin for a Buildfire plugin. I am currently hardcoding the API for google maps, but obviously for production, I would want the plugin to read from the integrations > API tab.

Does anyone have an idea or a snippet on how I may accomplish this?

I have searched the API docs at: https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/auth and have not been able to find the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly you can, following is an example how to get saved API keys from context:

```
buildfire.getContext(function(err, context) {console.log(context.apiKeys?.googleMapKey)})
```

https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/context#data

https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/api-keys#google-map-key

Comment: I really appreciate this!

Comment: @BruceKuka happy to help. Please mark it as an answer if it worked for you.